# Why display my list index out of range

Tags: python

i am coding binary search, I define a function ,and have 4 parameter, one of the parameter that number is the number you want to search ,but when i
input a big number which bigger than the last number of list ,the compiler will display the list index out of range, what is the connection between number and index?

```
list = [2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 20]

mid = len(list) / 2
left = 0
right = len(list)


def searchNumber(left, right, number, mid):
        while left <= right:
            mid = (right - left) / 2 + left
            if list[mid] == number:
                print("the local is in %d" % (mid))
                return mid
                break
            elif list[mid] > number:
                right = mid - 1
            else:
                left = mid + 1
```

Comment: i add a if that determine if the number is in the list ,then it works, but i also want to know why i get  this error

Comment: May be change `right` to `len(list) -1` . Also avoid using keywords as variable names. You should also add an `else` to the `while` loop for the case when `number` is not in the list

Comment: `right` is initially set to `9` and the `left` and `mid`after some iteration will reach to `9` when `list[9]` does not exist and hence the error

Comment: Sorry,i do not describe the question clearly, the coding is true . When i use searchNumber() directly ,i got an error, but when i use a = searchNumber(),then it makes good, i want to know why

Comment: Can you include the code how you are calling the function (both success and failure case)?

Answer (score 0):

```
list = [2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 20]

mid = len(list) / 2
left = 0
right = len(list)


def searchNumber(left, right, number, mid):
        **while left < right:**
            mid = (right - left) / 2 + left

            if list[mid] == number:
                print("the local is in %d" % (mid))
                return mid
                break
            elif list[mid] > number:
                right = mid - 1
            else:
                left = mid + 1
```

Comment: instead of 'while left < =right:' use 'while left < right:'

Answer (score -1):

I ran this code,

```
list = [2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 20]

mid = len(list) / 2
left = 0
right = len(list)


def searchNumber(left, right, number, mid):
    while left <= right:
            mid = (right - left) / 2 + left
            if list[mid] == number:
                print("the local is in %d" % (mid))
                return mid
                break
            elif list[mid] > number:
                right = mid - 1
            else:
                left = mid + 1
    return None

a = searchNumber(0, len(list)-1, 40, 40)
print "a =" + str(a)
b = searchNumber(0, len(list)-1, 9, 5)
print "b =" + str(b)
```

I got correct output in both the cases, where the asked number is present and the asking number is larger than the largest number of the list.

```
$ python pyt.py
a = None
the local is in 5
b = 5
```

I suspect the Error you get is because you're passing number which is negative or bigger than length-1 of the array, I don't see any other cases where you'll get "index out of range" Error.

Comment: I do not down vote the answer , when i use a = searchNumber(), i got right ,

Comment: Hi you have a return and Break inside the same loop, I don't understand the  use of it because code never hits break command. When I remove the break statement the code is working for just searchNumber(), when I pass the correct value for "left" and "right" arguments.

Comment: Actually the code works by just giving the correct values for left and right. Note that the right < len(list) and 0<= left < len(list). And also break statement is not required here.

Comment: yeah, return  or break can abandon